# How to make jar archive

Tags: java, csv, jar

I need to edit a CSV file which is in jar archive and then put it back in jar archive. I extracted the CSV file and edited it put it back in the archive using 7zip but the now the program which uses this archive gives an error.

So my question is how can I make a jar archive? Because I think if I extract the archive completely, edit the files and then make a jar again, then archive program wont give the error. I'm not much good with this stuff. Please, if there is an easy way  to do it with  software I'll be very glad.

I used jar command in cmd but it doesn't recognize this command.

Comment: Don't do that. Just save your CSV file outside of jar file.

Comment: will the program pick it up ?

Comment: Provide correct path and it will.

Comment: sorry im not a programmer...dont do how to do thats why need to pack it back in that archive

Comment: You might want to change the title and the exact content of the question. As it stands, this is kind of an XY problem. Instead of asking how to re-jar your jar, ask how to edit its contents in your program or simply save the CSV outside the jar as previously suggested.

Comment: Actually its an already made program...i need to change some values in it and these values are in a csv file packed in a jar archive. Previously already edited jar archive was available but now after update its not available, thats y i have todo it myself...im not good with this stuff so pardon me for not being able to put my question correctly :)

Comment: If someone can tell me how can i pack files (csv files) in a jar archive ill be grateful

Comment: You do that using the jar command. The jar command comes with the JDK. Make sure the JDK is installed, and you have its bin directory in your PATH environment varable.

Comment: thnkuu...where can i download jdk from

Comment: Are you seriously asking this question? How about googling for "download JDK"?

Comment: sorry i found it and was editing but it need five minutes

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you've already installed properly [Java SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).

Then, use the command line to create the jar file:

`jar cf jar-file input-file(s)`

or

```
<path_to_java_sdk>\bin\jar.exe cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

For more information, please check this link:
[Creating a JAR File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Java Tutorial say [there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html)

You can type:

```
jar uf jar-file input-file(s)
```

For example:

```
jar uf MyJar.jar new.csv
```

The `u` option stay for update, and the `f` indicates that the files are specified on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

And of course you can do next:

1. Extract archive.
2. Change csv file as you want.
3. Pack all file into zip archive.
4. Change an extension  of the given archive.

At least it works with war archives.